# C# not all code paths return a value when I declare a private string in a class method

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#.  This is, in fact my first project in this particular language.

In the following code:

```
namespace FuelBurnImport {

    class DataWriter {

        private string qs = "SELECT * FROM fuel_burn_data_meta;";

        public DataWriter(BurnDataHeader bdh, BurnDataFlight bdf) {
            SqlConnection cn = OpenCN();
            // work in progress.  more to be added here...
        }



        private SqlConnection OpenCN() {

            private string cs = @"Data Source=server; APP=FuelBurnImporter; Initial Catalog=database; Integrated Security=true";

                return new SqlConnection(cs).Open();
        }

    }

}
```

I get intellisense errors in the `OpenCN()` private method

- the `OpenCN()` method declaration says `Not all code paths return a
  value`

  the `{` following the `OpenCN() {` method declaration says `expected
  "}"`

  the end of line `private string cs` also says `expected "}"`

  the `cs` in `new SqlConnection(cs)` says `does not exist in current
  context`

  `new SqlConnection(cs).Open()` error says "a namespace cannot directly contain members..."

However, if I remove `private` from in front of `private string cs`, all these errors go away and it appears to be happy.

Am I misusing the `private` method in some way?  Am I misusing the private string declaration?  I have a feeling that even if I remove the `private` from in front of the string field declaration, it's still going to break.

Comment: please read up on some simple / free tutorials online in regards to void method vs methods that return a value. also you can't declare `private string cs` inside a method.. it's declared at the class level.. also `return cn` will fail to hence the Not all Paths return a value. you need to change the method to return the type. Before jumping in and following something you do not understand.. learn the basics first..

Comment: The failing will throw an exception so it should not cause this error, @MethodMan. I suppose it's a false error (C++ is not the only language guilty of this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string declaration within a method is local, so it makes no sense to make it private. Thus, you are committing a syntax error (and, in my view, a semantic error) by using the `private` keyword in there. The variable cn cannot possibly leak as it's inaccessible from other methods, and different instances of the same method on the same object have different "cs" things (I'm not sure but you can create a `private static const` string outside the method and use it in the method, if you really want to see "private" in the declaration of the variable).

Fix this first.

Before the actual return occurs, the "using" statement will automatically close the connection and you'd return a closed connection. This may or may not cause a syntax error, but if it does, I'd say it should be more explicit.

Comment: That `using` block won't cause a compile time error, but the connection will be unusable at run time. `using` should most likely be moved to the `DataWriter` constructor, if actual writing is going to happen right there (which is not so usual for constructors), so that the connection is closed after writing.

Comment: I'd propose a change so that returning something declared in the using block would give an error or at least a warning. While errors are breaking changes (they likely won't appear), warnings are to appear.

Answer (score 0):

1. After using block "}" - return null because using block only return the value not the function
2. No need declare private string inside function

Better way function implementation

```
private SqlConnection OpenCN() 
{
    string cs = @"Data Source=server; APP=FuelBurnImporter; Initial Catalog=database; Integrated Security=true"; SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs);
    cn.Open(); 
    return cn;
}
```

Comment: Wrong explanation at 1, but it did help me track the real cause. 2 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make cn a private member of the class;
2. Do not use using {} or dispose cn in an other way in OpenCN;
3. Implement IDisposable on your class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This works - the question is, does the connection need to be created and opened when the class is created and kept open until the class is disposed. If it has to be that way then do exactly this. But in most cases it's best to wait until you need the connection before opening it.

Comment: To address that concern, the way to use the DataWriter class would be to create one, call some data write methods and dispose it immediately after. This could be done using a using {} block.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `using` in `OpenCN`. `using` ensures that the variable created is disposed. If you do that you'll be returning a `SqlConnection` which has already been closed.

Instead, change `OpenCN` to this:

```
    private SqlConnection OpenCN()
    {
        var cs = @"Data Source=server; APP=FuelBurnImporter; Initial Catalog=database; Integrated Security=true";

        var cn = new SqlConnection(cs);
        cn.Open();
        return cn;
     }
```

Also, don't call `OpenCN` from the constructor. That's going to create an opened connection when you create an instance of `DataWriter`. Don't create and open a connection until you need it. That way you can create it, open it, use it, and then dispose it (which also closes it) as soon as possible.

Whatever the method is that's going to actually execute some SQL, create the connection there. If you call `OpenCN` from there, then you would do

```
using(var connection - OpenCN())
{
    //execute your SQL using the connection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your error, just remove the private keyword from the connection string declaration:

```
private string cs = @"Data Source=server; APP=FuelBurnImporter; Initial Catalog=database; Integrated Security=true";
```

However, you will have some problems because your connection will be closed as soon as using stament completes. Also it's not recommended to open your connections for long time. Simply make the using statement and open the connection just at the moment when you need to execute the query.